# Deleting files at different paths in macOS when the app is in sandbox mode

Tags: objective-c, macos, app-store, applescript, sandbox

I have an app, which I want to release on the Mac App Store and one of the features of the app is to delete files at different locations like :
Documents Folder, ~/Library/Preferences folder.. etc ..
I was doing that using :

```
    NSString *script =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"do shell script \"%@\" with administrator privileges", fullScript];
NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript new] initWithSource:script];
NSAppleEventDescriptor * eventResult = [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
```

Now the problem is that when in Sandbox mode this code doesn't work.
How do I delete multiple files from different folders by being in the sandbox mode ? Please help.

Comment: (1) Why do you even need to use AppleScript in order to delete files? (2) You can't just delete any file anwhere if the application is sandboxed.

Comment: How do I do that ? Please give me directions ...

Comment: Sir, are you saying it isn't possible when the app is sandboxed ?

Comment: The only way to do that is to use Application Scripts (`NSUserAppleScriptTask`)

Comment: Ok .. I will try that ... I have tried this : https://github.com/sveinbjornt/STPrivilegedTask
right now ... and it doesn't work in Sandbox mode ... will try using 
NSUserAppleScriptTask

Comment: Even if you do hack around the sandbox restrictions, AppStore reviewers will demand to know why your app needs to access _any_ resource outside its sandbox and will reject your App if you can't justify it. Therefore, instead of asking how to delete files not owned by your App, first explain _why_ you [think you] need to delete those files in the first place. Cos chances are your App either: 1. does things in really dumb/inappropriate ways (in which case folks'll tell you the right ways to do it), or 2. isn't the sort of App that's appropriate to AppStore anyway (e.g. system wrangling tools).

Comment: I was building an app for a particular malware removal ( tool ) ... So wanted to delete files which the malware was leaving behind ... that's the reason why I want to have right to delete certain threat files ... there is this OS Cleaner 3 ... I was making a mini version similar to it ...

Comment: I suspect that's not AppStore material, in which case there's no point you sandboxing it. You could try asking them, or look around to see how other developers distribute similar apps. (Main thing is that Apple knows the malware exists, as they periodically update their own security to deal with it. Any cleanup tools 3rd-parties release as interim measures are good community service.)

Comment: There is an antivirus called as Max Secure also ... I will contact Apple and have a word regarding it ...

Comment: `<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
 <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
    <array>
        <string>/</string>
    </array>`

Added this ... I am able to delete files from Documents, Desktop, /private/ but not from /Library/Application\ /Support/ or /Library/Preferences/ it says permission denied. I have to execute shell script with sudo which sandboxing doesn't allow, is there any other way ?